# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, maximize-window

I am trying to login page using below script but while maximize window it shows me below error.

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
>       from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
>         (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>       Command duration or timeout: 10.11 seconds
>       Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
>       System info: host: 'PRASANNAMULAY', ip: '172.21.31.80', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
>       Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>       Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9), userDataDir=C:\Users\PRASAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir12528_8422}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=57.0.2987.133, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
>       Session ID: 947fe656f81e3ced5cf5c932e81bc2f8
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:638)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:661)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.maximize(RemoteWebDriver.java:895)
>           at pract_1_phase_3.Pract_1_phase_3.main(Pract_1_phase_3.java:48)

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

My code is:-
package pract_1_phase_3;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;

import com.google.common.base.Function;

public class Pract_1_phase_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws AWTException {

    //  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Gecko\\geckodriver.exe");


        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
        prefs.put("password_manager_enabled", false); 
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("http://demo.actitime.com/");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("admin");

        driver.findElement(By.name("pwd")).sendKeys("manager");

        driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();

Please tell me whats steps i need to do to resolve above issue

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: Upgrade chrome driver version to 2.28 they fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to latest chromedriver.

This was a bug and was resolved in chromedriver v2.28. 
Refer: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Answer (score 1):

I too face the same issue recently. I took latest jar from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.29/ and added to my project. The issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\path\\to\\chromedriver");
```

and don't forget to add `selenium.jar` to your build path

Answer (score 0):

Screen flickering can also lead to this error.

solution reduce the window size to a screen becomes stable. 
I could resolve this issue by adding below code

```
 Dimension d = new Dimension(800, 600);
 driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
```